# Laravel form not returning input when I add 'files'=>true

Tags: php, forms, file, laravel

I have a form looking like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'notebook.store', 'files' => true)) }}
{{ Form::text('title', null, [
    'class'=>'form-control',
    'placeholder'=>'Title',
]) }}
<br>
{{ Form::text('description', null, [
    'class'=>'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'Desc',
])}}
<br>
{{ Form::file('path') }}
<br>

{{ Form::submit('Save', [
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right'
]) }}
<br><br>
{{ Form::close()}}
```

The problem is that `Input::all()` in my controller returns an empty array if that `'files'=>true` is in the form description, when I remove it, the problem goes away and `Input::all()` returns the usual, expected input.

Edit- I found out what the problem was. My server had terribly low post_max_size  in php.ini, and apparently it clears all your post/get data if the file exceeds that limit.

Comment: I tried to add `'files' => true` to one of my forms, and there was no problem with `Input::all()`. This option just adds `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` element.

Comment: Could be something server related, although I'm not sure what. Is it only when you add a file to upload or is it just always returning an empty array?

Comment: Is Input::file('path') in your controller empty?

Comment: I tried with both empty and populated 'path' field, in both cases the Input::all() array is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not receiving any POST data, you have to check for the [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) directive and comparing to how much POST data you are sending to the server.

As you already experienced, the behavior of having no post data is clearly described on the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

> If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty. This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if $_GET['processed'] is set.

The solution is to increase the value for [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), and/or also, [`upload_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) or even [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'notebook.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}
```

For any reason this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'notebook.store', 'files' => true)) }}
```

does not work!

Comment: {!! Form::model($article,array('method' => 'PATCH','route'=>array('articles.update',$article->id),'files' => true)) !!}
i have used this, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you are adding files=>true to the route array:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'notebook.store', 'files' => true)) }}
```

Instead try this

```
{{ Form::model(array('route'=>array('notebook.store'),'files'=>true)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'notebook.store', 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::file('logo', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

Comment: Can you add an explantion, why your idea woll solve the issue?